# Can JSHint detect when extra arguments are passed to a function?

Tags: jshint

For example, this won't trigger any warnings from JSHint, even though one of the arguments isn't used by the function, and isn't even part of the function signature.

```
function foo(x) { return x; }

foo(4, 5);
```

Comment: You would seem to have answered your own question.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't. The most likely reason for this is that a relatively common JavaScript pattern is to use the `arguments` collection to allow the passing of an arbitrary number of arguments. For example:

```
function findHighestNumber() {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, arguments);
}

findHighestNumber(1, 5, 19, 3); // 19
```

In this case, the function can accept any number of arguments and doesn't require any named parameters.

Comment: Thanks. That's unfortunate though. I did a code refactoring that removed arguments from functions, and afterward I found that I had a number of calls to the function that still had the extra arg. JSHint warns about other common patterns -- such as unused arguments in a function, and this one seems no more common or objectionable than that.